# How to use an Arduino to measure speed of rocket

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, rf, datalogging, speed

I am not very experienced with Arduino and I am trying to learn it. I was wondering what is the easiest and most effective way to calculate speed and log it every second so to say. This would be mounted in a model rocket to see what speeds it can reach. How would I achieve this?

Would it be hard to send over RF to see it in real time?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [accelerometer](https://diyhacking.com/arduino-mpu-6050-imu-sensor-tutorial/) or a [barometre](http://arduinolearning.com/code/bmp180-barometric-pressure-sensor-example.php) for measure speed and for RF you can use:

- [Radio NRF24L01](http://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-wireless-communication-nrf24l01-tutorial/)
- [wifi ESP8266](http://www.instructables.com/id/Quick-Start-to-Nodemcu-ESP8266-on-Arduino-IDE/)
- [bluetooth HC-06](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/user206876468/arduino-bluetooth-basic-tutorial-d8b737)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend WiFi for this. WiFi antenna patterns tend to be very flat to get a long lateral range, which means you don't get any height from them. A rocket will go high, and will rapidly lose WiFi connectivity. Bluetooth may not have the range required. The nRF+PA combo would be best.

Comment: I would recommend they start small. Learn to a get an LED to blink first. Baby steps. Learn c,c++ first. What they want to accomplish is way above their head.

Answer (score 0):

Quite different questions, but you need two items:

- A gyroscope/accellerometer, I don't think this should be a problem. You need to check beforehand if the Arduino is fast enough, since a rocket acceleration is probably very high.
- An RF transceiver, there are several types which work over big distances, but I don't have experience while they move fast. Maybe radio signals might get distorted, but for that hopefully someone has a better answer. Probably you cannot use a (big) external antenna which extends outside the rocket.